# Owl Carousel not working (Js conflict?) in IE11 win7

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, conflict, owl-carousel

This is my demo store url: http://axeonwater.websitetesting.us/
It's magento store. Owl carousel not loading in IE11 and I couldn't see any error in IE console can anyone help me with this.

This slider is working in html for reference please check: http://axeonwater.websitetesting.us/axeon-water

Answer (score 1):

There is a check and to-do.

If  Owl carousel is not latest upgraded version then please use the latest updated , they have fixed this issue.

If this does't solve the issue please check if you are using libraries using CDN url , if yes then download the files rather than using the CDN. In most of cases this was the issue.